# How to use web driver's dom elements even if that instance of driver is not active in selenium?

Tags: java, html, dom, selenium-webdriver

In selenium I am working on web pages.

I am trying multithreading here. Once a page is loaded, it will start processing this (interacting with DOM elements) in the backend, and move to next page.

Now after moving to the next page, it starts showing "No elements are attached" for the previous one.

How can I have access to DOM elements of the previous page even though I have moved to next page?

Comment: Please post your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't.

Every time the DOM is changing or even refreshed the elements previously located are not valid any longer and you need to relocate them (which you can't do if you moved to another page).

Further more, Selenium tries to simulate real user interactions with the webpage. If you can't do something manually, you can't do it using Selenium (Selenium can execute JavaScript commands that are able to do some things that aren't possible manually, but you still have to remain in the same page).